# ionic one tab go to another tab's child page can't go back to another tab

Tags: ionic-framework

ionic one tab go to another tab's child page can't go back to another tab

The problem: There's a button can go to state 'tab.settings.sub' in state 'tab.home' page, when first time I enter into state 'tab.home' , then click button to enter into state 'tab.setting.sub' but I can't go back to state 'tab.setting'.

```html
<ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

  <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab title="home" ui-sref="tabs.home">
        <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>
      <ion-tab title="settings" ui-sref="tabs.settings.index">
        <ion-nav-view name="settings-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
  </script>
  
  <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="home">
      <ion-content>
        <button class="button" ng-click="home.goSub()">settings/sub</ion-item>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/settings.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="settings">
      <ion-content>
        <ion-item ui-sref="tabs.settings.sub">settings/sub</ion-item>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>
  
  <script id="templates/sub.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="settings/sub">
      <ion-content>
        welcome to settings/sub
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>
```

The problem in http://codepen.io/piwinux/pen/BNYXKd

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the issue here is that you did not declared your "Home" tab abstract nor its substates in your `MyConfig.js`. In order to implement navigation in your "Home" tab you have to use the same pattern you have for the "Settings" tab:

- **tabs.home** state with `abstract: true` and `template: '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>'` to navigate in the tab.
- **tab.home.index** initial route of your "Home" tab with `templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'`.
- **tab.home.nextRoute** for the next route within "Home" tab using `$state.go ('tabs.home.sub');` instead of `$state.go ('tabs.settings.sub');` in your `HomeCtrl` to access it.

  `.state ('tabs', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/tab',
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })
  .state ('tabs.home', {
   abstract: true,
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'home-tab': {
      template: '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl as home'
      }
    }
  }).state ('tabs.home.index', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
  })
  .state ('tabs.home.sub', {
    url: '/sub',
    templateUrl: 'templates/sub.html'
  })`